# Is it possible to integrate AWS API Gateway private integration with ALB + VPC Link with ALB HTTPS listener?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement the pattern in [this](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/private-api-best-practices.pdf) link to front our apps behind an API Gateway. I first tried the same pattern with port 80 instead of port 443 to develop faster and verified that everything is working.(If I configure nginx proxy sidecar to listen port 80, use http listeners for my ecs tasks in my alb config and use the http_listener for the API GW VPC Link) Now, I would like to use https_listeners but what I have tried so far did not work.

When I configure nginx to listen on port 443, https listeners for my ecs task and use https_listener for the API GW VPC Link, it does not work. Here are the different combinations I tried:

- If I add a listener rule for port 80 and 443 and attach a redirection rule to https, I get the an 301 Moved Permanently error from my load balancer, which I believe means that the redirection did not work.
- If I only add a listener rule to port 443, I get a 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.

  [bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfw8Z.png)

What am I doing wrong? Any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks!

[ALB Architecture(ECS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CicVK.png)

Comment: If you have private ALB and private VPC link, why would you "care" about SSL/https for your internal traffic? I haven't tried myself, but if your API gateway exposes https endpoints and manages the SSL certificate, all subsequent internal traffic can safely go with http. Not really an answer, I know, but in case it helps..

Comment: I am planning to use api gateway as a front door for our resources in aws. Right now, it has an integration to route all the traffic to the https listener of my alb.(/{proxy+}). What do you mean by exposing the https endpoints with apigw? Doesn't that mean using the vpc link to link the gateway with my https listener.?How do I expose only the https endpoint of the gateway and tahe care of ssl there but use http for the internal traffic? @diegosasw

Comment: If your functionality is exposed through an Api Gateway, you can add the TLS (https) security there. I personally don't see any benefit in having the connectivity between Api Gateway and your internal AWS services through https because you already trust those connections.
Your application load balancer can use protocol HTTP on port 80 and that's fine if it's a private ALB (only accessible from API Gateway VPC link integration). And your services behind ALB can accept HTTP requests (without https) because requests are trusted (they come from your secured API Gateway)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I disabled https and moving forward with tls handled on api gateway, HTTP:80 listener.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.